# `return` code is being executed before Firebase call is finished fetching - swift

Tags: swift, firebase

The following function is suppose to fetch a list of **blocked-users** then fetch **blocked-by-users** merge the two lists and return it as a `[String]`.

The output to the console is the following which tells me that the `return` `blockedList` is being called early - **how can I force for the two observeSingleEvents functions are finished before passing the array back to the caller method?**

> 1 
>   4 
>   2 
>   3

```
func getBlockedUsersList() -> [String]{

    var blockedList = [String]()
    var blockedUsers = [String]()
    var blockedByUsers = [String]()
    print("1")

    DataService.run.getBlockedByUsersList { (success, blockedByUsersList) in
        print("2")
        if success {

            blockedByUsers = blockedByUsersList

            DataService.run.getBlockedUsersList(handler: { (success, blockedUsersList) in
                print("3")
                if success {

                    blockedUsers = blockedUsersList

                    blockedList = Array(Set(blockedUsers + blockedByUsers))

                }//end if-success

            })//getBlockedUsersList

        }//end if-success

    }//end getBlockedByUsersList

    print("4")
    return blockedList

}//end func
```

**Function `getBlockedByUsersList` gets list from Firebase:**

```
func getBlockedByUsersList(handler: @escaping (Bool, [String]) -> ()){

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    var blockedUIDs = [String]()

    REF_USERS.child(uid).child("blocked-by-users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children{

            let itemSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            blockedUIDs.append(itemSnap.key)

        }//end for

        handler(true, blockedUIDs)


    }) { (error) in
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}//end func
```

Comment: @rmaddy please help me understand - how is this a duplicate question to the one you've suggested?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't a duplicate? The better question is, if you know how to properly code an async method for `getBlockedByUsersList`, then why not do the same for `getBlockedUsersList`?

Comment: apologies but im new to this - so I wouldn't say I know how to code an async method (hence the question). I have read your suggested duplicate question and I am struggling to understand the likeness. In my code im making a nest `observeSingleEvent` nested calls, which I understand are `async` by nature. So my question is simple - how can I ensure that the first nested handler is returned, merged with the second prior to passing it to the caller?

Comment: You are already doing what you need to do in your `getBlockedByUsersList`. Use that exact same pattern in your `getBlockedUsersList` method (use a completion handler instead of a return value). The duplicate shows how to make that change. But again, you already have one method using the correct pattern. Just make the other one use the same pattern.

Comment: right that worked! - my initial intention was to try and make my code cleaner and simply just calling `getBlockedUsersList()` as parameter in another function to get the a merged `array`. I appreciate your help.